# How to remove a series from XYChartScrollbar in amCharts v4?

Tags: amcharts

How can a series be removed from the XYChartScrollbar in amCharts v4?

It was added in much the same way as series are added to the chart:

```
chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);
```

Removing it seems to remove it from the List (chart.scrollbarX.series.length goes from 1 to 0) but it remains on the scrollbar display.  I've also tried [removeIndex](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/list/#removeIndex_method), but no luck there either.

```
// removes from List, but still displayed
var scrollbarIndex = chart.scrollbarX.series.indexOf(series); 
chart.scrollbarX.series.removeIndex(scrollbarIndex);  

// same result, removed from List but still displayed
chart.scrollbarX.series.removeValue(series);
```

I have also tried calling [invalidate()](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychartscrollbar/#invalidate_method) and even [deepInvalidate()](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychartscrollbar/#deepInvalidate_method) to try to get the scrollbar to refresh but no success.

An example pen is at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrQvbw?editors=0011.  Clicking on a toggle button adds the series to the chart and scrollbar, but only removes it from the chart.

Comment: I've made [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/785) in regards to removing a series from the scrollbar ought to remove it from its `scrollbarChart`, if you've an account there please subscribe for further updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing a series from the scrollbar itself does not seem to remove the series from the [scrollbar's chart](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychartscrollbar/#scrollbarChart_property) which itself is a whole other chart with distinct series. Going to look into this more and get back to you.

In the meantime, we can piggy back off of the scrollbar's `removeValue` method via the series' `List`'s [`"removed"` event](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/list/#removed_event), to do the same thing on `scrollbarChart`. The `scrollbarChart`'s series are all clones of the original chart's series, presuming a series only ever has 1 clone and that that clone is within `scrollbarChart`, this code seems to do the trick (`removed.oldValue` is the series we just removed from `scrollbarX.series`):

```js
chart.scrollbarX.series.events.on("removed", function(removed){
  chart.scrollbarX.scrollbarChart.series.removeValue(removed.oldValue.clones.getIndex(0));
});
```

Here's a fork of your demo with that addition:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1b623a1b4ddf6a198bc80bdf5f5e1514

Comment: Awesome support from amCharts as always.  Getting "EventDispatcher is disposed" when I integrate the solution into Vue, but that is a topic for another post.

Comment: We appreciate the high praise! =)